# Get all activities from a Google+ page and access the content

Tags: php, arrays, api, object, google-plus

I`m trying to obtain all activities from a G+ page using [Google PHP Api Client](https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client):

```
$service = new \Google_Service_Plus($this->client);
    $activities = $service->activities->listActivities($data['page_id'], 'public');
```

The result is an array of `Google_Service_Plus_Activity` objects. The problem is that I want to access the content of one of the activities to search for a string, but this is under `["modelData":protected]=> array(1)` as `["content"]=> string(int) "my_string"`. Is there a possibility to access the content?

`var_dump($activity)`:

```
  object(Google_Service_Plus_Activity)#268 (28) { ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=> array(0) { } ["accessType":protected]=> string(23) "Google_Service_Plus_Acl" ["accessDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["actorType":protected]=> string(33) "Google_Service_Plus_ActivityActor" ["actorDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["address"]=> NULL ["annotation"]=> NULL ["crosspostSource"]=> NULL ["etag"]=> string(57) ""RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/t4CM2-QFWMd8gXogVxXGqNUhGSA"" ["geocode"]=> NULL ["id"]=> string(35) "z133dxyyhuaqf5tqd04cebxrtuykyfc5vi0" ["kind"]=> string(13) "plus#activity" ["locationType":protected]=> string(25) "Google_Service_Plus_Place" ["locationDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["objectType":protected]=> string(34) "Google_Service_Plus_ActivityObject" ["objectDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["placeId"]=> NULL ["placeName"]=> NULL ["providerType":protected]=> string(36) "Google_Service_Plus_ActivityProvider" ["providerDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["published"]=> string(24) "2015-03-20T09:03:51.236Z" ["radius"]=> NULL ["title"]=> string(103) "http://www.company-civ.localhost.com/provider/endpoint/validation_social/google?validate=017f5b8e-cee0..." ["updated"]=> string(24) "2015-03-20T09:03:51.236Z" ["url"]=> string(63) "https://plus.google.com/104620991895987671420/posts/akiK7Yx6eus" ["verb"]=> string(4) "post" ["modelData":protected]=> array(4) { ["actor"]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(21) "104620991895987671420" ["displayName"]=> string(27) "Magazin de scule barbatesti" ["url"]=> string(45) "https://plus.google.com/104620991895987671420" ["image"]=> array(1) { ["url"]=> string(98) "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50" } } ["object"]=> array(6) { ["objectType"]=> string(4) "note" ["content"]=> string(264) "http://www.company-civ.localhost.com/provider/endpoint/validation_social/google?validate=017f5b8e-cee0-11e4-8698-448a5b89d5f1ï»¿" ["url"]=> string(63) "https://plus.google.com/104620991895987671420/posts/akiK7Yx6eus" ["replies"]=> array(2) { ["totalItems"]=> int(0) ["selfLink"]=> string(90) "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z133dxyyhuaqf5tqd04cebxrtuykyfc5vi0/comments" } ["plusoners"]=> array(2) { ["totalItems"]=> int(0) ["selfLink"]=> string(98) "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z133dxyyhuaqf5tqd04cebxrtuykyfc5vi0/people/plusoners" } ["resharers"]=> array(2) { ["totalItems"]=> int(0) ["selfLink"]=> string(98) "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z133dxyyhuaqf5tqd04cebxrtuykyfc5vi0/people/resharers" } } ["provider"]=> array(1) { ["title"]=> string(7) "Google+" } ["access"]=> array(3) { ["kind"]=> string(8) "plus#acl" ["description"]=> string(6) "Public" ["items"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(6) "public" } } } } ["processed":protected]=> array(0) { } } object(Google_Service_Plus_Activity)#269 (28) { ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=> array(0) { } ["accessType":protected]=> string(23) "Google_Service_Plus_Acl" ["accessDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["actorType":protected]=> string(33) "Google_Service_Plus_ActivityActor" ["actorDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["address"]=> NULL ["annotation"]=> NULL ["crosspostSource"]=> NULL ["etag"]=> string(57) ""RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/Z-Jgsn-qD_7-wIVme1yMD5E2Y6k"" ["geocode"]=> NULL ["id"]=> string(33) "z13pt1n4owmog3peg22lzhyirobmu1ivk" ["kind"]=> string(13) "plus#activity" ["locationType":protected]=> string(25) "Google_Service_Plus_Place" ["locationDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["objectType":protected]=> string(34) "Google_Service_Plus_ActivityObject" ["objectDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["placeId"]=> NULL ["placeName"]=> NULL ["providerType":protected]=> string(36) "Google_Service_Plus_ActivityProvider" ["providerDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["published"]=> string(24) "2015-03-20T08:35:56.611Z" ["radius"]=> NULL ["title"]=> string(103) "http://www.company-civ.localhost.com/provider/endpoint/validation_social/google?validate=1c09b6ce-cedc..." ["updated"]=> string(24) "2015-03-20T08:35:56.611Z" ["url"]=> string(63) "https://plus.google.com/104620991895987671420/posts/Dpn1rWu44Dp" ["verb"]=> string(4) "post" ["modelData":protected]=> array(4) { ["actor"]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(21) "104620991895987671420" ["displayName"]=> string(27) "Magazin de scule barbatesti" ["url"]=> string(45) "https://plus.google.com/104620991895987671420" ["image"]=> array(1) { ["url"]=> string(98) "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50" } } ["object"]=> array(6) { ["objectType"]=> string(4) "note" ["content"]=> string(264) "http://www.company-civ.localhost.com/provider/endpoint/validation_social/google?validate=1c09b6ce-cedc-11e4-8c62-448a5b89d5f1ï»¿" ["url"]=> string(63) "https://plus.google.com/104620991895987671420/posts/Dpn1rWu44Dp" ["replies"]=> array(2) { ["totalItems"]=> int(0) ["selfLink"]=> string(88) "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z13pt1n4owmog3peg22lzhyirobmu1ivk/comments" } ["plusoners"]=> array(2) { ["totalItems"]=> int(0) ["selfLink"]=> string(96) "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z13pt1n4owmog3peg22lzhyirobmu1ivk/people/plusoners" } ["resharers"]=> array(2) { ["totalItems"]=> int(0) ["selfLink"]=> string(96) "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z13pt1n4owmog3peg22lzhyirobmu1ivk/people/resharers" } } ["provider"]=> array(1) { ["title"]=> string(7) "Google+" } ["access"]=> array(3) { ["kind"]=> string(8) "plus#acl" ["description"]=> string(6) "Public" ["items"]=> array(1) { [0]=> array(1) { ["type"]=> string(6) "public" } } } } ["processed":protected]=> array(0) { } } object(Google_Service_Plus_Activity)#272 (28) { ["internal_gapi_mappings":protected]=> array(0) { } ["accessType":protected]=> string(23) "Google_Service_Plus_Acl" ["accessDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["actorType":protected]=> string(33) "Google_Service_Plus_ActivityActor" ["actorDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["address"]=> NULL ["annotation"]=> NULL ["crosspostSource"]=> NULL ["etag"]=> string(57) ""RqKWnRU4WW46-6W3rWhLR9iFZQM/YjJYiH1WPwlvGXudZ_Hq21fjRLc"" ["geocode"]=> NULL ["id"]=> string(35) "z13eun0r1tikx3lju04cebxrtuykyfc5vi0" ["kind"]=> string(13) "plus#activity" ["locationType":protected]=> string(25) "Google_Service_Plus_Place" ["locationDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["objectType":protected]=> string(34) "Google_Service_Plus_ActivityObject" ["objectDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["placeId"]=> NULL ["placeName"]=> NULL ["providerType":protected]=> string(36) "Google_Service_Plus_ActivityProvider" ["providerDataType":protected]=> string(0) "" ["published"]=> string(24) "2015-03-20T08:34:31.517Z" ["radius"]=> NULL ["title"]=> string(103) "http://www.company-civ.localhost.com/provider/endpoint/validation_social/google?validate=e51795c8-cedb..." ["updated"]=> string(24) "2015-03-20T08:34:31.517Z" ["url"]=> string(63) "https://plus.google.com/104620991895987671420/posts/iubGf6imv4c" ["verb"]=> string(4) "post" ["modelData":protected]=> array(4) { ["actor"]=> array(4) { ["id"]=> string(21) "104620991895987671420" ["displayName"]=> string(27) "Magazin de scule barbatesti" ["url"]=> string(45) "https://plus.google.com/104620991895987671420" ["image"]=> array(1) { ["url"]=> string(98) "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-XdUIqdMkCWA/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAAAAA/4252rscbv5M/photo.jpg?sz=50" } } ["object"]=> array(6) { ["objectType"]=> string(4) "note" ["content"]=> string(264) "http://www.company-civ.localhost.com/provider/endpoint/validation_social/google?validate=e51795c8-cedb-11e4-88a6-448a5b89d5f1ï»¿" ["url"]=> string(63) "https://plus.google.com/104620991895987671420/posts/iubGf6imv4c" ["replies"]=> array(2) { ["totalItems"]=> int(0) ["selfLink"]=> string(90) "https://www.googleapis.com/plus/v1/activities/z13eun0r1tikx3lju04cebxrtuykyfc5vi0/comments" } ["plusoners"]=> array(2) { ["totalItems"]=> int(0) ["selfLink"]=> string(98) "https://www.googleapis.com/plus..
```

Comment: @Grigor Florin - are using this: https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client ?

Comment: Yes, I use that bundle.

Comment: Then I guess a simple `foreach` will do the trick for you. Could you add in your answer `var_dump($activities)`?

Comment: No, because it cannot be accessed. You can access other properties such as title, etc.

Comment: What about `var_dump($activities)`?

Comment: I've tried listing activities here and `content` is visible: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.list?userId=%252Bgoogle&collection=public&_h=1&

Comment: Here is a different story. It's about an object, and the content is under  `["modelData":protected]=>` which is, obviously, protected. There (in your example) you receive a JSON.

Comment: I think I've found the solution for you. After you use `listActivities`, you should use `get` method for each activity and then get the `content`. Dive in here https://github.com/google/google-api-php-client/blob/master/src/Google/Service/Plus.php for more info.

Comment: My assumption above is not right. I still want `var_dump($activities)`. If you add it to your answer, I think I could help you. Add `array('maxResults' => 2)` as a third parameter of `listActivities` to dump only 2 results.

Comment: Yes indeed. There is no method ->get() in this object context. Maybe a solution would be to obtain activities in a JSON format.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is (found it finally):

```
$service = new \Google_Service_Plus($this->client);
//you can also set range of post (max 100)
$optParams = array('maxResults' => 100);
$activities = $service->activities->listActivities('{PAGE_ID}', 'public',$optParams);

foreach($activities as $activity) {
   $result = $activity->getObject();
}
```

The `$result` is an Object which contains a public property, `content`
So:

```
$result->content;
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access the content by using: `$activity->getObject()->content`

Answer (score 0):

I will shoot a little bit in the dark. But you will tell me if this is working:

```
foreach($activities as $activity) {
    $activityInfo = $service->activities->get($activity["id"]);
    var_dump($activityInfo);
}
```

Not sure if the `id` is on this level of the array becuse `var_dump` is not very tidy. But an example id is this `z133dxyyhuaqf5tqd04cebxrtuykyfc5vi0`

Try this approach and tell me if it's working. (Or at least we are on the right direction)

Regards

Comment: It's not working: `$activityInfo` resulted is the same object with the same structure.

Comment: Very strange. I've tested it here: https://developers.google.com/apis-explorer/#p/plus/v1/plus.activities.get?activityId=z133dxyyhuaqf5tqd04cebxrtuykyfc5vi0&_h=3& and `content` should be present there. (According to the docs from Google)

Comment: I'm not familiar with the API, so I can only make assumptions. Glad you've found the solution yourself. @Beniamin Szabo should get a credit as well.

Comment: We are colleagues (with @Beniamin Szabo), we work on the same project. The debug was made on his machine :)

Comment: Heh. Great :) Team work! Glad you've solved your problem. It will help others for sure. That's the idea in SO, people work together to solve problems. I did not contribute, but I tried. Regards